# Comparing Time in Python between String and Naive format

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I need to compare the time between two dates in python. One is given as a string and the other in datetime.datetime format. I have tried a few ideas, but the error is always `Cannot compare tz-naive and tz-aware datetime-like objects`

Idea 1: Convert the string time into pandas Timestamp. Then reconvert into string. Then convert to isoformat. Then compare new isoformat to datetime.datetime object

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
time_to_compare = datetime.utcnow()-timedelta(minutes=60)
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
df['Date'] = df['Date'].apply(lambda x: str(x))
df['Date'] = df['Date'].apply(lambda x: datetime.fromisoformat(x))
df= df.loc[df['Date']>=time_to_compare]
```

Idea 2: Change the datetime.datetime object to a Timestamp

```
time_to_compare = pd.to_datetime(datetime.utcnow()-timedelta(minutes=60))
df['Date']=pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
df= df.loc[df['Date']>=time_to_compare]
```

Ideally I want to filter the dataframe and say if time_to_compare is less than df['Date'] keep said element in the dataframe.

Use to test:

```
d = {'Date':['2020-03-12T13:59:15.739Z','2020-02-28T22:22:06.827Z']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

Comment: The error says that one in TZ aware, and the other is naive. It would help if you shared at least one example...

Comment: Updated to share an example. Apologies.

Comment: The code in *Idea 2* works on my pandas 0.23. What is your version?

Comment: I have version 1.0.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

wih Pandas 1.0.1, you can add `utc=True` while creating `time_to_compare` like:

```
time_to_compare = pd.to_datetime(datetime.utcnow()-timedelta(minutes=60), utc=True)
```

to make it timezone aware

Answer (score 0):

I could not reproduce, because on my Pandas 0.23, `df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])` gives a naive pd.Timestamp column wich can be compared to `datetime.utcnow()-timedelta(minutes=60)` which is *by definition* naive.

If your system is able to build `df['Date']` as a timezone aware column, you should just build a timezone aware `time_to_compare` with:

```
time_to_compare = datetime.now(timezone.utc)-timedelta(minutes=60)
```